# Does this distribution belong to the exponential class

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I've come across a following problem:

$$
f(x; \mu, \sigma^2) = e^{\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}(ln x - \mu)^2}, \quad x>0
$$

Does this distribution belong to the exponential class?

To be honest, I have no idea how to show that...

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Definition)

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Probability_density_function).